# Why is this C code not working?

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to insert two random strings in each node, but when I print the list the output is not correct. What can it be? I'm not good at memory allocation, so if anything is wrong please explain me. I also tried to see if a string was overwriting another, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node{
    int times;
    char name[100];
    char number[100];  
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node* node;

void mklist(node* n){
    *n=(node)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    (*n)->times=0;
    strcpy((*n)->name,"null");
    strcpy((*n)->number,"null");
    (*n)->next=(node)NULL;
}

void listins_beg(node* n,char name[],char num[],int tim){
    node a;
    a=(node)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(a==NULL) exit(1);
    a->times=tim;
    strcpy(a->number,num);
    strcpy(a->name,name);
    a->next=(node)(*n);
    (*n)=a;
}

void printlist(node n){
    node x;
    x=n;
    if(x->next==NULL) printf("EMPTY LIST");
    else{
        do{
            printf("%s - %s\n",x->name,x->number);
            x=x->next;
        }while(x->next!=NULL);
    }
}

void freelist(node* n){
    node x;
    for(;x->next!=NULL;(*n)=(*n)->next){
        x=(*n);
        free(x);
    }
}

int main(void){
    node n;
    mklist(&n);
    listins_beg(&n,"Hermanouhuhuuteu","4523-2248",300);
    listins_beg(&n,"Luhu","4523-4887",299);
    listins_beg(&n,"Lulamolute","4523-4687",512);
    printlist(n);
    freelist(&n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct node* node;` No, please, just *no.* This obfuscates your code *horribly.* It's best not to typedef pointers at all, so that semantics are immediately visible. But this is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I tried using `typedef struct node node`, but it gave me a lot of errors and headaches :/

Comment: Use more different identifiers and try again.

Comment: It's quite hard to wrap one's head around pointers, at beginner and even intermediate programmer levels. Don't make it even harder by hiding the fact that pointers are involved. It's quite natural to assume `X` is a non-pointer type and `X*` is a pointer (for any `X`). You're making this harder for yourself by having to think about what is a pointer and what is not without the `*`s to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You did `typedef struct node* node` in your code.But in your functions `makelist` and `listins_beg` you have used

```
 *n=(node)malloc(sizeof(node*));
 a=(node)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Now here `*n` is a pointer to `struct node` but it is allocating memory only `8 byte` or `4 byte` depending on your machine as `sizeof(node*)` will return 8 or 4 because `node*` is a `pointer to pointer` to a `node`,same things happens while allocating memory for `a`.It should be rather like this

```
 *n=(node)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //in makelist
 a=(node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));  //in listins_beg
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as angew points out you need to get rid of

```
  typedef node* node;
```

You need to review the basics of how structures work. For example in main you declare;

```
    node n;
```

Then in mklist(..) you try to allocate the struct. But your declaration already allocated it. If you want to allocate structures, declare pointers then allocate the struct and set the pointer to point to the new memory just allocated;

```
  node *p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: Note that due to the OP's *extremely confusing and obfuscating* typedef, `node` is an alias for `struct node *`.

Comment: Yes, that should be fixed. I just didn't want to repeat your correct observation above.

Comment: However, without mentioning and applying the change (of removing the typedef), this answer is incomplete, as it cannot simply be used with the OP's code.